# Page content dissapears when using MySQLs' count

Tags: php, mysql

I want a tab on my menu that states howmany tasks somebody still has to do. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
 public function getTasksCount() {
        $stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE for = ?");
        $user = $_POST['user_name'];
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($count);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                return "$count";
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

But when I call it like this `<?php $adminfunctions->getTasksCount(); ?>` most of my pages content dissapears. (See picture below.) As you can see, the vertical side-menu is still alright, but there are options from the top menu gone and ofcourse the content in the big whitespace... Any help?

Img:[image: Stuff disapears...]

Comment: you're doing a `select count(*)` query. it can only ever return a single row. so using a `while()` loop to fetch that row is a major symptom of cargo-cult programming. And if your page dies after a particular bit of code, you've probably got an error that kills php and debug options are disabled, preventing the error messages from being displayed. are error_reporting and display_errors turned on? They should never be off while debugging/developing.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, they're turned on.

Comment: If the missing content is sent after `getTasksCount()` is called, i suppose that your function produces an error and this error is not displayed, persumably because of the setting of display_errors and error_reporting directives in PHP.

Comment: You should probably check num_rows BEFORE you do your fetch/store_result stuff. not sure exactly what all store_result does internally, but it may throw off metadata like num_rows.

Comment: You could also check the page source in your browser. The line `return "$count";` in your case returns the query result converted to a string, maybe there are some HTML reserved characters in this string which then affect the display of the page.